# Is it faster to send objects in bulk than individually?

Tags: java, networking

Quick question. I have a game with a bunch of zombies moving around. I need to send  every zombie's position from the server to the clients. Would it speed up the process if I collected all the positions and sent them in one big package, instead of each position being sent individually? Or does it make any difference?

If it depends on platform, I'm coding in Java and using Kryonet for networking.

Comment: If you are sending to a mobile device, imo it is better to send as a big batch, because opening and closing connections drains batery, afaik.

Comment: Make sure you have read time out set to bigger value on the socket if you are sending bulk data and you are expecting a response from the server by processing theat bulk input

Comment: @Sunny The server is sending the objects to the client, not the ther way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bulk it needs less percetage overhead than each individually of course. Each tcp/ip packet has an header, in bulk the header is needed less often than individual packets.
Same applies for the communication protocoll.

However for games, consider udp if realtime behaviour is needed; Then you have to look what fits into one udp packet.